# "Invalid Token" when trying to authenticate in IOS real device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

Hi have tried to use the phone authentication from firebase, but it is failing. I have read a lot of question regarding this problem and most of them mentioned to create the apn key in developer.apple.com

Maybe that could work, but the thing is that I have used the phone authentication in another apps that have access to the same firebase project and I didn't add any apn key.

[image]

For "Delivery Clientes" I can authenticate using phone number, but for "DeliveryAppRestaurant" not.
This is my third app using authentication with phone number, but I don't know what I'm missing (I know that i have never create an apn key, so I think that's not necessary). I think that I'm forgetting something.
I already add the URL at info Runner
[image]

And I'm still receiving the exception of: [firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token.

And this is only happening when I tested in real device, in the simulators works fine. Any thoughts?

regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If somebody face the same problem than me. It seems that if your app have notifications services:
[image]

You should add apn key on firebase:

[image]

Also if you have problem with connection recaptcha, you can add the following lines on AppDelegate

```
 //Auth
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
           let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
           firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
 }
 override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
           let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
           if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
               print(userInfo)
               return
           }
}
```

Comment: hello friend, where did you write that code?

Comment: Did you get where to add those lines or any other working solution

Answer (score 1):

Nice! This works for me. I create key in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Key (Create & Download), and put them in Firebase Cloud Messanging.

[image]